# Store a list in a variable in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to store a list in a variable and use it later in different parts of SQL?

I have a sql like this
As shown the list content is duplicated.
I tried to use `DECLARE` or `DEFINE` but seems like it is not for this case

```
SELECT 
    l.cod
FROM list l
WHERE l.cod IN ( '1999', '1998', '1997' ...) --- same list

UNION

SELECT 
   l.cod
FROM list l JOIN blablabla.... 
WHERE l.cod IN ( '1999', '1998', '1997' ...) --- same list
```

How can I solve this in a better way?

Comment: Have you considered storing in a temp table?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use that list as a "source" for query which will split it to rows, and then use that CTE as "source #2" for your current query.

Something like this:

```
with list (col) as
  -- this is your list
  (select q'['1999', '1998', '1997']' 
   from dual
  ),
splist as
  -- list, split to rows
  (select trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level)) val
   from list
   connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
  )
-- OK, now we're set to use it
select l.cod
  from list l
  where l_cod in (select val from splist)   --> it is used here
union 
select l.cod
  from list l join blabla on a = b
  where l.cod in (select val from splist);  --> and here
```